# Где расположен конфиг nginx в CentOS-7

Tags: nginx, centos7

/etc/nginx/conf.d

Я так понимаю это общий конфиг. А отдельно для каждого сата, то есть есть 5-10 сайтов, для каждого сайта тоже есть свой конфиг nginx? По какому пути он расположен в CentOS-7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда `nginx -T` выведет весь конфиг Nginx со всеми инклудированными файлами.

Для каждого сайта вы можете прописать свой конфигурационный фвйл и поместить его /etc/nginx/conf.d или все прописать в одном файле.